# " ex.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done' 'x.sh: line 11: `done <$1 " error

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to read a csv file using the following script
But I am constantly encountering the error

```
ex.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token \`done' 
'x.sh: line 11: \`done <$1
```

Please help me out

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
while read f1 f2 f3 f4
    do
        echo -e "\n
        $f1\n\
        $f2\n\
        $f3\n\
        $f4\n"  
done <$1
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

This is the command I am using: `bash ex.sh file.csv`

Comment: Did you write the script in an editor that saved it as a DOS text file? In that case run `dos2unix` on the script and consider writing you script with a Unix text editor instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks a lot, it was indeed the EOL problem.

Answer (score 0):

You heed to provide the csv file an a first parameter:

```bsh
./x.sh /home/data.csv
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I have already provided the filename; following is the command I am using

**bash ex.sh file.csv**

Comment: Try to hardcode the file path, to make sure that it's not that.